# Possible to make full loop on a swing only by "pumping legs"?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, home-experiment, estimation

Is it possible to make a full $360^{\circ}$ loop on the type of swing in a children's playground if I power the swing only by "pumping" my legs? i.e. nobody pushes me?

Comment: Not with a swing that us suspended by rope or chain. It can be done with a rigid swing, which is a standard circus act.

Comment: The Mythbusters did it with a swing with chains ... but they used rockets.

Comment: Curious - quite a claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's solve this in two parts. First, I will calculate how fast you need to go at the bottom of the swing in order to be able to make a complete loop (without the rope going slack). Next, I will estimate whether you can achieve this speed by "pumping" - that is, moving your center of gravity around to increase your speed.

### Part 1: speed needed

The velocity you need can be determined from the length of the swing. If the rope is length $\ell$, you need to go fast enough that you are able to resist the force of gravity at the top of the loop.

At the top of the loop, you have lost some speed due to gravitational potential: $\Delta E = 2 m g \ell$. And in order to have sufficient acceleration to counter gravity, you need a speed to keep the rope taut:

$$\frac{m v_{top}^2}{\ell} \gt m\;g$$

This means that the swing needs to move with a minimum velocity (at the bottom) of

$$v_{bottom} \gt \sqrt{g\;\ell + 4\;g\;\ell} = \sqrt{5\;g\;\ell}$$

Note - this does mean that you will feel significant g forces at the bottom of the swing... Don't try this with your toddler!

### Part 2: doing it under your own steam

In principle this only depends on the friction forces on the swing, and how much energy you can add per "pump". However, I think in practice the answer will be "no" - and here is why:

The action of "pumping" on the swing is basically an application of conservation of angular momentum. By moving your center of mass closer to the center of rotation, you increase your velocity. There is a very nice explanation of this [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/188469/26969). The key on a swing is that you "pump" near the bottom of the swing, when it is going fast; and you "release" when you get to the end of the swing (where your velocity goes to zero). Normally, you move just a short distance, and add just a little bit of energy. But to make a full loop, you need to add sufficient energy in a single "pump" to go all the way around.

So let's assume you were making a 180° swing when you decided to try to add the additional angular momentum. This is the most you can swing without the rope going slack (unless you do a full 360). In this case, the velocity at the bottom of the arc is

$$v_{init} = \sqrt{2\;g\;\ell}$$

Now you need to increase your speed in a single "pump" to $\sqrt{5\;g\;\ell}$ to reach the velocity calculated above - but in effect you are changing $\ell$ when you pump, so we would need to take that into account.

You can do this if you can move your center of mass closer to the center of rotation. If you stand on the swing and push yourself up, you might move the center of gravity from $\ell$ to $\ell'$. If you continue standing, you will be making a tighter circle which will help at the top of the swing.

In this scenario, the velocity (you standing) at the bottom of the swing $v_b'$ has to be sufficient to get you to move up by $2\ell'$ - in other words, we need

$$v_b' = \sqrt{5 \;g \;\ell'}$$

and we know from conservation of angular momentum that $$v_{init} \ell = v_b' \ell'$$

Now we can solve for $\ell'$. A bit of manipulation shows

$$\ell'^3 < \frac25 \ell^3\\
\ell' < 0.74 \ell$$

This means that if you can raise your center of mass by about 25 % of the distance from the seat of the swing to the pivot, you could do a loop.

Assuming you are a 180 cm person with 80 cm legs, you can raise your center of mass (from crouch to standing up) by about 40 cm. If that is 25% of the distance to the pivot, you would need a very short swing - rope length no more than 160 cm. You might hit your head... and the force you need to do this is very significant (you are lifting more than twice your weight). If you can't do a deep squat with a friend sitting on your shoulders, you will not be able to do this.

I think the answer is "maybe; but don't try it at home..."

Comment: Sorry, I means without the help of another children. With just movement with my legs

Comment: @sailx it would help if you stated that in your question...

Comment: Yes, I'm really confuse I was too into the problem... I'm sorry to have forget about this !

Comment: Floris -- Not in the spirit of criticism, but "your handy editor suggests..." it is quite confusing that you (completely missed :) ) the point of the question at first. Wouldn't it be more sensible to delete the irrelevant part up front, which is quite confusing? There  seems to be no point at all for that now completely redundant section. Have a nice day!

Comment: @JoeBlow - the result is needed for the second part. I agree it could use a bit of editing to flow better. Thanks for the constructive input.

Comment: Physics of "pumping" a swing (not unlike skateboard in a half pipe??) *"The key on a swing is that you "pump" near the bottom of the swing, when it is going fast"* .. hmm. IS THIS RIGHT?  For me I "pump" (twist - or something) only at the TOP (beginning) of one swing. And possibly at the end, I'm not sure.  I just hold-firm during the bottom of the arc.  I have to look up some thinking on this now!  (Also, it's unclear if one's "legs" have anything to do with it [even though I emphasised that in my helpful edit to the OP].  I'm just not sure.  I more just move my body in-out - I think!)

Comment: @JoeBlow - you move your center of mass up and down. Move it far from the center of rotation when you are stationary, then push closer while you go fast. The fact that you are pushing against the apparent centrifugal force should tell you that you are adding energy to the system. Moving when you are stationary takes no force and does no work.

Comment: Hmm- ok, I'm sure you're right.  I thought I moved myself either in-out towards the axis, or, fore-aft along the tangent at any moment .. I may well be wrong.

Comment: See an example of the kind of pumping I was talking about in [this video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3FrvV3It5U) - but note that this swing has a solid "rope" which allows the person on the swing to add momentum over many iterations, with the final velocity only just enough to rach the top (much less than needed with a flexible rope).

Comment: Hmm .. this animation (yellow) perfectly seems to express how you "pump" a swing.  I, for one, have never seen anyone do ANYTHING at the bottom of the stroke ... http://www.physicsinsights.org/up_in_a_swing.html

Comment: the video seem to precisely show the performer doing nothing, at the bottoms!

Comment: (Sure, a solid swing is completely different from a rope!  I wish I could simulate rope with as few cycles as solid bar  :) :) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24723/discussion-between-floris-and-joe-blow).