Does centripetal acceleration affects the magnitude of velocity?
A vector has no component in the perpendicular direction, obviously.
But let us consider a situation where a ball is moving in a uniform circular motion tied to a string, then $a = \dfrac {v_1^2} r$.
Suppose after some time the acceleration is increased to 2 times the original one. Now $2a = \dfrac{v_{2}^2}{r}$.
The string has the same length therefore $r$ remains unchanged $\implies$ magnitude of velocity must have changed.
The change in acceleration is also in the direction of acceleration at any point that is perpendicular to the direction of velocity. Then, how does the velocity increase.

You go from $a = \dfrac {v_1^2} r$ to $2a = \dfrac{v_{2}^2}{r}$ in two ways. You could increase the centripetal acceleration, but this is a centre pointing force and this would decrease the radius. In order to keep the radius constant, you increase v first by accelerating the orbiting object first tangential to the radius. The centripetal acceleration then increases as result of increasing tangential velocity and not the other way around, in the constant radius scenario.

Since you are fixing the radius, an increase in the centripetal acceleration implies an increase in the speed. This necessitates a tangential acceleration. So during the increase, the acceleration is not radially inward. It is not perpendicular to the velocity and has a component along the velocity. There is no contradiction.

Does that mean if the mass of sun was somehow doubled, since there would be an increase in force directed towards center only and no tangential force, it would be impossible for earth to revolve any faster (while remaining at the same distance), and it would necessarily shorten the radius making the earth spiral towards the sun. Am I right?

@MathMathMath The situation you describe is different from the above. In your original question you were considering constant radius. However in this example the variable that is constant is not radius but angular momentum. So the radius decreases and the speed increases.

@MathMathMath Note that as the object spirals inwards (i.e. its velocity has both tangential and radially inward components), the radially-inward force does cause the speed to increase. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185240/174766 for more information. There is again no contradiction.

That is what I wanted to know

It seems that your confusion is just due to standing the physical facts on their head: if you actually do rotate such a ball via a string, how do you actually increase the centripetal acceleration? That is, how do you increase the tension in the string that must be equal to the centripetal force in magnitude? I suspect you already know the answer: you rotate the string faster!
So that intuitively, if we look at the kinematic relation:
$$ a_r = \frac{v_t^2}{R} $$
We see that for a fixed $R$, a uniform circular motion with tangential speed $v_t$ requires a centripetal acceleration $a_r$.
Of course, you can also think of it backwards if you really want: If you see a ball of mass $m$ rotating by a string and you measure that the tension in the string is $T$, then plug in $a_r=T/m$ in the above equation to find its tangential speed $v_t$.
But, is it because of the fact that the tension in the string is exactly $T$ that the ball is moving with this exact tangential speed $v_t$? That's a physically backwards, or at least odd, way to think about it, because it's much more intuitive to think about how in the process of rotating the string faster, it responds by increasing its tension and hence the centripetal acceleration $a_r$. Indeed, if we increase the rotation speed enough, any real string will rip at the point where its material can no longer provide the required tension $T$.

Suppose you have a object on a string moving in a circle on the surface of a table, with the other end going through a hole in the table attached to a weight. The weight must be of particular mass to provide just the right amount of tension/centripetal force to keep the object moving in a circle at its particular velocity.
If you increase the weight on the end of the string, the weight will descend and the string length will shorten. The particle won't simply move faster in the same orbit, the orbit itself will change. If you manually increase the speed of the object as you add weight, however, the object can keep the same orbital path with a higher velocity.
Centripetal acceleration and orbital velocity need to be exactly in balance to maintain a circular orbit. There isn't always a requirement that acceleration and velocity must remain in balance to keep a circular orbit if one changes, though - unless the object is physically restricted to its orbit there's no reason the orbit must remain a circle. It's perfectly acceptable to change the acceleration or velocity, and rather than seeing the other one change to the "matching circular orbit value", we see the orbit change shape instead.

You cannot magically increase that acceleration and expect the radius to stay the same. That centripetal acceleration formula is a mathematical relationship; when you fix the speed, then the radius and acceleration are in inverse proportion to each other. There is no way around mathematical facts.

There may be some logical inconsistencies in your statement.  You prescribe an increase in centripetal acceleration by increasing the velocity from $v_1$ to $v_2$.  This acceleration has to come in the radial (velocity) direction.  Now, to keep the ball in circular motion, a string force is needed that is double in magnitude.  But you ask "how does the velocity increase?"  Well, it increases because you increased it.  Unless I am misunderstanding your question.
Maybe this will clarify your confusion.  If you want a ball to accelerate linearly (not in a circle) in some direction, you apply a force in that direction.  That is straightforward (pun intended).  Now, if you want your ball of mass $m$ moving with speed $v$ to trace the path of a circle with radius $r$, you need to apply a sideways force equal to $mv^2/r$. If you apply a different force, you will end up with a different $r$.  If the string (source of force) is suddenly cut, the ball will go back to straight line motion.  In other words, the force or centripetal acceleration aren't constants.  If you prescribe a particular motion, then they are simply the requirements for staying on that path.

I am simply asking if the centripetal acceleration changes to something else let's say it doubles, then why should magnitude of velocity change as it is perpendicular to the centripetal acceleration. Only its direction may change but that does not happen as the length of the string is fixed.

If the centripetal acceleration doubles, then the centripetal force doubles.  Like if you somehow had an actuator on the string.  If the force doubles and everything else stays the same, your ball will find a new smaller radius to turn at. Or at least it will get knocked out of the original circular orbit. And you are right that the velocity will NOT change.  But you can't just say "double the centripetal acceleration" and not let anything else change.  Because that isn't consistent with circular motion.

Let's say that suddenly Earth's gravity increased such that the centripetal acceleration of a satellite in circular orbit doubled.
This would cause a greater turning effect of the satellite's motion than what it needs to keep up the circular orbit. So it would start curving downwards, achieving an angle that is no longer perpendicular. The gravitational force is thus no longer perpendicular, and hence it causes a tangential acceleration which will indeed speed up the satellite (and it will also start forming an elliptical orbit).
If you wish to avoid that and to keep the satellite in a circular orbit at the same radius, then you have to induce a tangential acceleration which is not caused by the Earth's gravity. Maybe you have a small rocket engine on the satellite. This tangential acceleration must then increase the speed until your formula is fulfilled again.
