Conservation of angular momentum about axis
A small particle is projected with an initial velocity tangent to the horizontal rim of a smooth hemispherical bowl of a radius $R$ from the vertical central line. 
As the particle slides down, its speed increases. The component of velocity along the tangent to a horizontal circle at any instant also increases, as can be seen from conservation of angular momentum. Torque due to normal reaction and weight is zero about the vertical axis, but I am not able to identify the force responsible for increasing the horizontal component of velocity along the tangent. 
Which force is responsible for this as both normal reaction and weight are perpendicular to this component at any instant?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185240/174766

So is it due to the fact that radius of the circle is decreasing as given in one of the responses or that there has to be a component of force along the tangent.
